# Как сделать такую же подскаску в VS Code как в WebStorm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, webstorm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как сделать такую же подсказку в VS Code как в WebStorm? Работая WebStorm понравилась данная фича как такую же сделать в VS Code, на скриншотах у людей видел что есть такая возможность

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liamhammett.inline-parameters

Comment: Этот работает вроде как быстрее https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DominicVonk.parameter-hints

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй вот это расширение. Подсказки можно стилизовать как в WebStorm. С WebStorm конечно не сравнится. Она немного криво работает. Сам попользовался пару дней и удалил.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liamhammett.inline-parameters

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]